# PostgreSQL Find entries within a certain timespan from timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a few tables that have entries with a time stamp without time zone (for example: '2014-06-23 11:48:31')

Now, I want to get all of the entries of the tables that have a time stamp between 7 and 9 AM.

Comment: what have you done so far?.. what difficulties you met? why not  `date_part('hour',ts) in (7,8,9)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the hour:

```
where extract(hour from ts) between 7 and 8
```

This works because the time frame you are looking for exactly conforms to hours.  I think this is a bit simpler than converting to a time data type.